# Database column based record filtering not working using auto-complete search PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have integrated auto-complete search in my site where user enter keyword and view the records based on it.

Suppose, if I write zip code it only filter data from zip field. Next, if user types address like 121 North West, so script automatically pick records matches 121 North West. Moreover, same for street, if user type street name like cedar lane, it then fetches records from database field street only.

I am having problem that it searches the records from all fields and so I am unable to get proper listing from database.

Referense site I am following is [http://www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com/) here this is working as expected. I want the same on my site and it works but not like I expects.

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$searchKeyword  = $_REQUEST['keyword'];

$searchQ    =   "SELECT zip, ste, st, st_num, town, addr FROM tbl_property WHERE (zip = '$searchKeyword' OR ste like '%$searchKeyword%' OR town like '%$searchKeyword%' OR addr like '%$searchKeyword%') GROUP BY zip LIMIT 0,5";
$queryRec   = mysql_query($searchQ);
$recSet     = mysql_num_rows($queryRec);
echo "<div id='fetchRecs'><ul>";
if($recSet>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryRec)) { 
        echo '<li>'.$row['addr'].', '.$row['town'].', '.$row['ste'].', '.$row['zip'];?></li>
    <?php
            }
        }else{
    echo "<li>No Records Found</li>";       
    }
echo "</ul></div>";
```

I simply want if user writes 123, list shows like 1234,1245, and same like listing that show only zip codes from zip column.

Same, If user write 123 cedar it picks listing similar to 123 cedar only means it will come from street column.

P.S: I am having only one text field in which I type keyword like: http://www.trulia.com

**P.S: My question is still not resolved, please share if anybody have any useful information. May be it will work for some other as well.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First of all, perdon me for my mistakes.***

Ok, i changed a few things and now is working:

```
//Filter:
<?php

  if (isset($_REQUEST['field']) && isset($_REQUEST['keyword'])) {
    $field = $_REQUEST['field'];
    $keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
  }else{
    $field = null;
    $keyword = null;
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_property";
  $where = "";
  switch ($field) {
      case 'zipCode':
          $where = " WHERE zip like '" . $keyword . "%'";
          break;
      case 'addr':
          $where = " WHERE addr like " . $keyword . "%";
          break;
      case 'city':
          $where = " WHERE city like " . $keyword . "%";
          break;
  }
  $query = $query . $where;

  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
  if ($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die($db->connect_error);
  }

  $result = $db->query($query)
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Searcher</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

    <section id="searcher">
      <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"           />
      <input type="hidden" name="field" id="field" value="all" />
      <div id="lists">
        <ul></ul>
      </div>
      </form>
    </section>

    <section id="results">
        <table>
          <caption>Results</caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Zip</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>City</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo ($row['zip']); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo ($row['addr']); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo ($row['city']); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>      
    </section>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#keyword" ).keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "req.php",
            data:{ key: $(this).val() },
            success: function(data){
                //Show the data to the clients
                //(in a div or a "select2" plugin)
                if (data.locations.length > 0){
                  $('#lists ul').html('');
                  $.each(data.locations, function( key, location ) {
                      //iterate over locations
                      $('#lists ul').append( '<li data-field="' + location._type + '">' + location.value  + '</li>' );
                  });

                  //SetUp hidden default value while keyword change
                  //Form the JSON Response
                  $('#field').val(data.locations[0]._type);
                }else{
                  $('#lists ul').html('No Results!');
                  $('#field').val('all');
                }
            }
        });
      });

      $('#lists ul li').click(function(){
          $('#keyword').val($(this).html());
          $('#field').val($(this).parent().data('field'));
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>

<?php
  $db->close();
?>
```

and

```
//req.php
<?php
$key = $_POST['key'];

$data = array(
              'locations' => array(),
              'errors'=>array(),
              'success'=> true
              );

header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$query = "SELECT zip FROM tbl_property WHERE zip LIKE '" . $key . "%';";
$zips = $db->query($query);

$query = "SELECT city FROM tbl_property WHERE city LIKE '" . $key . "%';";
$cities = $db->query($query);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$index = 0;
if ($zips){
  while($row = $zips->fetch_assoc()){
      $data['locations'][] = array(
          "value"=> $row['zip'],
          "altValue"=> null,
          "display"=> $row['zip'],
          "_type"=> "zipCode",
          "propertyIndex"=> "",
          "index"=> $index
      );
      $index = $index + 1;
  }
}
if ($cities){
  while($row = $cities->fetch_assoc()){
      $data['locations'][] = array(
          "value"=> $row['city'],
          "altValue"=> null,
          "display"=> $row['city'],
          "type"=> "city",
          "propertyIndex"=> "",
          "index"=> $index
      );

      $index = $index + 1;
  }
}

$db->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

i did not run a test to the click event on the `lists ul li`  element, because i don't know what would you do, and is the less important part.

I hope that was what you was looking for.
keep in touch.

Comment: First, of all thank you for the great response in terms of fixes and now the code working for me. I must say its the most optimized and working code you have developed for me as it resolved all of my issues. :) thank you again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

---

### UPDATED

---

This is the form from http://www.trulia.com/

```
<div class="searchbox">
  <form id="searchbox_form" class="searchbox_form form man" method="get" action="/submit_search/" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="field man">

      <span class="select">
        <div id="homepage-select" class="selectPretty">
          <select id="search_options" class="h5 man txtL" name="display_select" data-previous-selection="for_sale">
              <option value="for_sale">Buy</option>
              <option value="for_rent">Rent</option>
              <option value="sold">Recently sold</option>
          </select>
          <div class="selectDisplay btn btnLrg btnDefault rrn backgroundBasic pts plm">
            <span class="selectLabel h5">Buy</span>
            <span class="selectTrigger pts"><i class="iconDownOpen"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span class="text">
        <div style="display: none; top: 129px; left: 297.5px; width: 370px;" class="autosuggest_list"><ul><li class="location-get-me">Current Location</li></ul></div><input id="searchbox_form_location" type="text" name="search" class="searchbox_form_location searchInput text searchByLocation typeWeightNormal h5 man" value="" placeholder="Search by neighborhood, city, zip or address" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="locationId" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="locationType" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="tst" class="searchbox_form_type" value="h">
        <input type="hidden" name="ac_entered_query" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="ac_index" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyId" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyIndex" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="display" class="searchbox_form_type_display" value="for sale">
        <button class="btn btnPrimary submit"><span class="h5 typeEmphasize"><i class="iconSearch h4"></i>SEARCH</span></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

also if you filter the GET requests that the page made you can se that while you insert a value in the text bax a json is requesting by ajax:

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "value": "47977",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19901",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "value": "47978",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19902",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "value": "47979",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19903",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 2
    }, {
        "value": "47980",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19904",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 3
    }, {
        "value": "47981",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19905",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 4
    }],
    "suggestions": [],
    "success": true,
    "errors": []
}
```

that is similar to the last example that I first give you (using ajax setting a hidden vaule input for your search), and then in your php file you can switch for that hidden input value, that in the json is `"type": "zipCode"`

You can read the last method again with these additional information.

If I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

---

if you want to get separeted lists for each type of search that your clients will search, you can put another input referring to the type of the search:

```
<select name="field">
    <option value="zip">Zip Code</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="keyword" />
```

then in your php code:

```
$field = $_REQUEST['field'];
$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_property";
$where = "";
switch ($field) {
    case 'zip':
        $where = " WHERE zip = " . $keyword;
        break;
    case 'addr':
        $where = " WHERE addr like " . $keyword . "%";
        break;
    case 'city':
        $where = " WHERE city like " . $keyword . "%";
        break;
}
$query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY zip LIMIT 0,5";
```

That will give you a separeted list depending in what the client search for.

Other form of doing it would be analyzing the data in keyword, for example you know that if you have only 1 word that also could be transform into a number, it's referring to a zip code

you can use arrays for that:

```
$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_property";
$where = "";
$parms = split(" ", $keyword);
if(count($parms) == 1 && intval($parms[0], 10) > 0){
    $where = " WHERE zip = " . $keyword;
}elseif (count($parms) > 1){
    $where = " WHERE addr like %" . $keyword . "%";
}
```

that will depends on your own logic.

if I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

---

***MOD 03/05/2015 8:00:00 p.m.***

You can also use javascript and ajax to get the list of citys, zip codes and addrs that you have and set in a hidden input the type of search that you will made. For example, using jQuery:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"           />
<input type="hidden" name="field" id="field" value="all" />
<div id="lists"></div>

<script>
    $('#keyword').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "req.php",
            data:{ key: $(this).val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('#lists').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#lists ul li').click(function(){
        $('#keyword').val($(this).html());
        $('#field').val($(this).parent().data('field'));
    });
</script>
```

on req.php

```
$key = $_POST['key'];

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

$query = "SELECT zip FROM tbl_property WHERE zip like " . $key . "%;";
$zips = $db->query($query);

$query = "SELECT addr FROM tbl_property WHERE addr like " . $key . "%;";
$addrs = $db->query($query);

echo ('<h1>Zips</h1><ul data-field="zip">');
while($row = $zips->fetch_assoc()){
    echo ("<li>" . $row['zip'] . "</li>");
}

echo ('</ul><hr /><h1>Addrs:</h1><ul data-field="addr">');
while($row = $addrs->fetch_assoc()){
    echo ("<li>" . $row['addr'] . "</li>");
}
echo ('</ul>');

$db->close();
```

If I didn't miss anything it should work.

If I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you very much for great explanation but I am afraid it cant help me getting through this search. What I need is: if you view [http://www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com) and search for zip it only fetches zips, If user type street number: it only get all street number (No Zip, No Address). Same if user types address, search comes up with matched addresses only (No Zip, No Street). So, first there is only one input field no drop-down no filter, we need to filter database column that my issues.

Comment: Can you please visit [http://www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com) and search your home, near by zip and then you will see what I need. Your code doesn't help me. Kindly help me get through this.

Comment: so actually you are referring you last example to [http://www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com) site? I mean this will work? As previously I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post complete working example in separate question please? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your strategy, you can use JSON like the web [www.trulia.com](http://www.trulia.com), or html response among others.

your html file, using the json method, remember to define your own logic!:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
<input type="hidden" name="field" id="field" value="all" />
<div id="lists"></div>

<script>
    $('#keyword').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "req.php",
            data:{ key: $(this).val() },
            success: function(data){
                //Show the data to the clients
                //(in a div or a "select2" plugin)
                $.each(data.locations, function( key, value ) {
                    //iterate over locations
                }

                //SetUp hidden default value while keyword change
                //Form the JSON Response
                $('#field').val(data.locations[0].type); //Get the type of the first element in locations
            }
        });
    });
    $('#lists ul li').click(function(){
        $('#keyword').val($(this).html());
        $('#field').val($(this).parent().data('field'));
    });
</script>
```

the req.php file:

```
$key = $_POST['key'];

$data = array(
              'locations' => array(),
              'errors'=>array(),
              'success': true,
              );

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$query = "SELECT zip FROM tbl_property WHERE zip like " . $key . "%;";
if(!$zips = $db->query($sql)){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$query = "SELECT city FROM tbl_property WHERE city like " . $key . "%;";
if(!$cities = $db->query($sql)){
    $data['errors'][] = $db->connect_error;
    die(json_encode($data));
}

$index = 0;

while($row = $zips->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['locations'][] = array(
        "value": $row['zip'],
        "altValue": null,
        "display": $row['zip'],
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": $index
    );

    $index = $index + 1
}

while($row = $cities->fetch_assoc()){
    $data['locations'][] = array(
        "value": $row['city'],
        "altValue": null,
        "display": $row['city'],
        "type": "city",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": $index
    );

    $index = $index + 1
}

$db->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The JSON Response like in trulia.com:

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "value": "47977",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19901",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 0
    }, {
        "value": "47978",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19902",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 1
    }, {
        "value": "47979",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19903",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 2
    }, {
        "value": "47980",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19904",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 3
    }, {
        "value": "47981",
        "altValue": null,
        "display": "19905",
        "type": "zipCode",
        "propertyIndex": "",
        "index": 4
    }],
    "success": true,
    "errors": []
}
```

in your search php file (the one that will search when the user submit)

```
$field = $_REQUEST['field'];
$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_property";
$where = "";
switch ($field) {
    case 'zip':
        $where = " WHERE zip = " . $keyword;
        break;
    case 'addr':
        $where = " WHERE addr like " . $keyword . "%";
        break;
    case 'city':
        $where = " WHERE city like " . $keyword . "%";
        break;
}
$query = $query . $where . " GROUP BY zip LIMIT 0,5";

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$result = $db->query($query);

// show the result

$db->close();
```

If I didn't miss anything it should work.

If I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

Comment: Matias: I am really thank ful to you for this kind help. But I am afraid your code has numerous JSON and array syntax errors. can you please look into them. Moreover, for reference please visit this url where I am getting error and wants to implement it. URL is: [http://www.realtyexecutivesny.com/indextest.php](http://www.realtyexecutivesny.com/indextest.php)

Comment: the line `$('#field').val(data.locations[0].type); //Get the type of the first element in locations` has `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error. Even my ajax call is also not passing through.

Comment: working with JSON will be more better as it will be much faster for my case. So it will be much better using JSON if JQuery got fixed.

Comment: your function does not seems working for me and it have bugs too. Please try to rectify the code if you can and always make sure to post working code only for future. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I had a lot of work, i will test the code again, because i can't find the error. As soon as possible i will respond

Comment: No problem. :) I am too having some meeting schedules in past days. I tried your new code and it worked for me. Thank you please for your great help. :)